# Reg: FULLTEXT Search

Tags: php, mysql

We are using FULLTEXT search one of our project, But its taking too much time to load. We have only 5lakh data.

```
SELECT category_id, subcat_id, MATCH(product_name, product_desc) AGAINST ('cd player' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score 
FROM `products_details1` WHERE MATCH(product_name, product_desc) AGAINST ('cd player' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

before mysql_query :::0.0026848316192627

> $result = mysql_query($query, $db_connection1);

After mysql_query :::21.530656814575

If we are running the same query from phpMyadmin, its taking 0.8430 sec...

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have a fulltext index on product_name, product_desc?

Comment: I have added FULLTEXT for both the fields using, create FULLTEXT index posttext ON <tablename>(product_name, product_desc)

Comment: probably, huge amount of time was spent on data sending. in case of phpMyAdmin - it uses pagination, so only first 20 or etc rows was fetched

Comment: @GodwinSam Instead of phpmyadmin run from workbench.

Comment: how to find the duration and status for query profile FULLTEXT BOOLEAN MODE for phpMyadmin